# Marketing Cloud SOAP API - How to Retrieve Latest Subscribers?

Tags: apex, marketing-cloud, soap-api, integration, wsdl2apex

How to perform a retrieve request to retrieve the LATEST subscribers from Salesforce?

```
<soap:Body>
  <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
     <RetrieveRequest>
        <ObjectType>Subscriber</ObjectType>
        <Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
        <Properties>Client.ID</Properties>
        <Properties>EmailAddress</Properties>
        <Properties>SubscriberKey</Properties>
        <Properties>Status</Properties>
        <Properties>UnsubscribedDate</Properties>
        <Properties>EmailTypePreference</Properties>
        <Filter xsi:type="ns1:SimpleFilterPart" xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
           <Property>Status</Property>
           <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
           <Value>Active</Value>
        </Filter>
     </RetrieveRequest>
  </RetrieveRequestMsg>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to target the "[ListSubscriber](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/listsubscriber.htm)" Object where the CreateDate is a recent value ([greaterThan](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/simpleoperators.htm) %%date%%).

Assuming only "Active" subscribers are being added to your All Subscribers List only, you can use the simple filter below:

```
<Property>CreatedDate</Property>
<SimpleOperator>greaterThan</SimpleOperator>
<Value>%%Variable Date Here%%</Value>
```

Comment: I am gonna use the subscriber object but I want it to be retrieve in descending order. Right now it's all the oldest subscribers getting retrieved.